# What is deps.json, and how do I make it use relative paths?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm setting up an ASP.NET Core project on TeamCity. The binaries it builds crash on startup on other machines. The error message shows that it is looking for dlls in paths that only exist on the build server. DotPeek shows that there's an embedded resource file in the .exe called `myproject.deps.json`. In the targets section there, there are references to dlls using absolute paths. This means that ASP.NET Core binaries are only ever going to run on the machine on which they were built.

How do I fix this problem? What is this file, and how do I make it use relative paths? After some digging, it looks like the paths come from `project.fragment.lock.json`, which is a generated file. If I edit this to use relative paths, the file is just overwritten again. What generates this, and how can it be fixed, or stopped?

For those who asked, `project.json` looks like:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "CommandLineParser": "1.9.71",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "System.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Company.Common": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Company.Integration": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Company.Functions": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Company.Utils": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Those absolute path references are to third party libraries?

Comment: @Evk Some of them, others are references to in house libraries.

Comment: Is TeamCity installed on your machine, or on separate server? Is dotnet version is up-to-date? What part of deps.json contain path to libraries - can you compare with locally-build one and show us some differences?

Comment: @Dmitry TeamCity is installed on a build server. Yes, .NET Core was installed yesterday. It's the targets section of deps.json. The only difference is the paths.

Comment: Does your project name contain whitespace?
Can you post your `project.json`?

Comment: @Hypnobrew Project name does not contain whitespace. Question edited to include `project.json`

Comment: Did you use `dotnet publish` during your build to create a copyable output? just using `dotnet build` for project.json is not guaranteed to produce a deployable output (It was designed to be faster for "inner loop" development)

Answer (score 23):

The answer to your first question, per the [Runtime Configuration File Documentation:](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/Documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md)

And the answer to your second question, is to remove **preserveCompilationContext** in your project.json file (and rebuild).

> **MyApp.deps.json** is a list of dependencies, as well as compilation context data and compilation dependencies. Not technically required, but required to use the servicing or package cache/shared package install features.

Per your comment to Dimitry, I couldn't tell if you have .net core installed in your target machine and therefore infer the kind of deployment you are trying to do. But assuming it is installed, you should be able to tune your **myproject.runtime.json** to fix your problems. In case you don't, I highly recommend reading about the two different types of [.NET Core Application Deployment:](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/deploying/index.md)

> You can create two types of deployments for .NET Core applications:
>
> **Framework-dependent deployment**. As the name implies,
> framework-dependent deployment (FDD) relies on a shared system-wide
> version of .NET Core to be present on the target system. Because .NET
> Core is already present, your app is also portable between
> installations of .NET Core. Your app contains only its own code and
> any third-party dependencies that are outside of the .NET Core
> libraries. FDDs contain .dll files that can be launched by using the
> dotnet utility from the command line. For example, dotnet app.dll runs
> an application named app.
>
> **Self-contained deployment**. Unlike FDD, a self-contained deployment
> (SCD) does not rely on any shared components to be present on the
> target system. All components, including both .NET Core libraries and
> the .NET Core runtime, are included with the application and are
> isolated from other .NET Core applications. SCDs include an executable
> (such as app.exe on Windows platforms for an application named app),
> which is a renamed version of the platform-specific .NET Core host,
> and a .dll file (such as app.dll), which is the actual application.

Comment: I don't have a `myapp.deps.json` on disk. It's being automatically generated by (I assume) VS, and embedded in the application.

Comment: @TarkaDaal if you want to get rid of myproject.deps.json in your assembly, you can remove preserveCompilationContext in your project.json file (and rebuild).

Comment: @ciriate That was it! Make this an answer and you can can the bounty.

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/main/documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md

Answer (score 18):

`*.deps.json` comes from `preserveCompilationContext`.

Preserving the compilation context is useful for runtime compilation (i.e. just-in-time compilation) and especially for compiling views. It is not usually useful for libraries. To fix your problem:

1. Remove `preserveCompilationContext` from each `Company.*` library that your app references.
2. If that does not work, also remove `preserveCompilationContext` from your main app.

There is an involved conversation here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5141

Comment: I added this in my netstandard2.0 project and still get deps.json

Comment: I added this in my net6.0 project and still get deps.json

Answer (score 13):

If you are using the newer .csproj format

Adding `<PreserveCompilationContext>false</PreserveCompilationContext>` under the `<TargetFramework>` tag fixed the issue for me.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>false</PreserveCompilationContext>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I added this in my netstandard2.0 project and still get deps.json

Comment: I added this in my net6.0 project and still get deps.json

Comment: Such elements are independent and `Under` has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

After a full search finally found my solution, this was my case:
- only happens when run

> dotnet publish

so in order to solve this, edit your **csproj** and make sure to have this configuration.

This apply to webapi netcoreapp 2.0

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>false</PreserveCompilationContext>
</PropertyGroup>
```

this also will solve problems related to

> "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found"

ref.: https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation/issues/162
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/279

Comment: God bless you!
Worked on my .net framework 4.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had the following error message:

An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyApp.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'PropertyChanged.Fody', version: '3.4.0'
path: 'lib/netstandard2.1/PropertyChanged.dll'

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/issues/543)

In csrpoj you need

```
            <PackageReference Include="PropertyChanged.Fody" Version="3.4.0" PrivateAssets="All">
                <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
                <IncludeAssets>All</IncludeAssets>
            </PackageReference>
```

Comment: That was the only solution that worked for me. I was having the same problem trying to run xUnit tests with Resharper using net6.0 and Anotar.Fody.