# .NET 6 Project builds successfully but won't build during any 'dotnet ef' command

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2022

I have an EF Core data layer project that is part of a bigger solution. It targets:

- Output Type = Class Library
- .NET 6.0 (Windows)
- Target OS Version = 10.0.19041.0
- Supported OS Version = 10.0.19041.0

It builds successfully in the normal way in Visual Studio, however when building as part of (for example) issuing a 'dotnet ef migrations list' command in the Package Manager console, it fails with:

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (DataProvider2.deps.json) was not found:
> package: 'runtimepack.Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref', version: '10.0.19041.25'
> path: 'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll'

I have tried

- Making the data project the startup project.
- Removing the other projects so it's the only project in the solution.

What I don't understand is where it's getting '10.0.19041.**25**' from. I can't find it anywhere in any metadata files. I can't install the Nuget Package (`dotnet add package Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref --version 10.0.19041.25`) as it targets the .NET Framework.

Where else could this reference be coming from?

Comment: I think this might be related https://stackoverflow.com/a/41000887/1927444

Comment: Nothing in that link works unfortunately - the deps.json file still gets created no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

As always enlightenment comes *after* you post an SO question.

I created a new project and copied all the code into it and verified that it worked with EF Core commands. I then compared the .csproj files.

Apparently this is bad:

```
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
```

but this is good:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

In case that helps anyone else.

Comment: this was it. nice job!