# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, directoryservices, notsupportedexception

I get this exception when debugging:

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement is not supported on this platform.

and call stack starts as:

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType) in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.notsupported.cs

I am running on Windows, I am targeting:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

and I use this package:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" Version="7.0.0" />
```

`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` is supposed to work on Windows but I can not find what makes it think that it is on a different platform.

Any help will be much appreciated!

People have reported this error when using linux or docker deployments but I am using windows 10, and some people report that it is due to using

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
```

I have moved all my projects into

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

but it is still throwing this exception.

Comment: Is this of any help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73713047 ?

Comment: I tried this but no difference. :( Why does debugger think I am not running on Windows?

Comment: You only get that problem when debugging? If you run the compiled exe it does work?