# Error launching .NET app on another machine

Tags: .net

After publishing my .NET application as self-contained and into a single .exe file and sharing it with two friends I found out it didn't work.

It runs fine for me and one of my friends but the second gets an error:

`cannot use file stream for NameOfProject.deps.json: no such file or directory`

When I published as a single file it shouldn't depend on any extra files, right? I told him to create a new file with the same name and add an empty object but it also didn't work.

As a side note, all of us are running windows 11 x64 and have .NET's latest version.

Comment: See if removing the need for that file helps like in one of the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40849745/64348).