# error The specified deps.json [] does not exist

Tags: .net, compiler-errors, json.net

I am building an app in .net 8 and blazor, and when I want to do my first migration to the database I get the following error: The specified deps.json [D:\C# Projects in visual studio\APPVales\SistemaGestionEmpleados\Client\ bin\Debug\net8.0\Client.deps.json] does not exist. The project compiles fine, but when I want to start the migration I get that error.

These are the references I have in my Client.Program:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

   <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
     <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
     <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Blazored.LocalStorage" Version="4.5.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="8.0.2" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="8.0.2" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="8.0.2" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons" Version="24.2.7" />
     <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Blazor.Popups" Version="24.2.6" />
     <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes" Version="24.2.6" />
   </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
     <ProjectReference Include="..\BaseLibrary\BaseLibrary.csproj" />
     <ProjectReference Include="..\LibreriaCliente\LibreriaCliente.csproj" />
   </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and these are the references I have in

```
Client._import.razor:

@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Http
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@usingClient
@using Client.Layout

@using LibreriaBase.DTOs
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using LibreriaCliente.Helpers
@usingLibraryCliente.Services.Contracts


@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthStateProvider
@inject IUserAccountService
@inject NavigationManager NavMager
```

If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.

I tried cleaning the solution several times and recompiling it, I also tried closing and reopening visual studio but the error continues

Comment: i think your problem expained in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849745/what-is-deps-json-and-how-do-i-make-it-use-relative-paths